# deployed nuxt on aws static websites not showing sitemap and blog

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, nuxt.js, vs-web-site-project

Guys pls would you advise what to check? I am using nuxt and on localhost I can simply type localhost/sitemap.xml and can get there and the same with content. But on production I cannot see anything :frowning: Its hosted on aws static websites. New to this :frowning: Pls would you advise what to check? Its using cloudflare as well. There is printscreen added

EDIT: after running locally "npm generate" and "npm start" all the routing and everything works. As soon as I deploy to aws even the nuxtjs/content dynamic routing is not working :(

UPDATE: sitemap issue resolved by @NicolasPennec by adding xml into redirects of AWS -> </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|xml|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>

SECOND QUESTION: similar issue using nuxtjs/content module (in attachements) -> I run locally nuxt generate and it creates static html fine in dist. And routing is working locally as well. As soon as I deploy routing shows main index.html file (in attachement). I hardcoded route to nuxt config. But still not working on aws :(

[Image of prod vs local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzUsk.png)

[dist structure with content module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yp14.png)

[blog redirect issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKI0M.png)

```
export default {
 target: 'static',
 mode: 'universal',

  head: {
   titleTemplate: 'Love Cayman Islands',
   title: 'lovecaymanislands',
   htmlAttrs: {
     lang: "en",  // it sets the language English
   },
   meta: [
     { charset: 'utf-8' },
     { name: "HandheldFriendly", content: "True" },
     { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
     { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Love Cayman Islands shares info about moving and living in Cayman Islands | Advice about job, hotel, appartment, house in Cayman Islands' },
     { hid: 'keywords', name: 'keywords', content: 'video, blog, life, rum point, west bay, cayman islands jobs, cayman islands property' }
   ],
   link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon-green.png' },
   {
     hid: "canonical",
     rel: "canonical",
     href: "https://www.lovecaymanislands.com",
   }]
 }, 
  css: [
   '@/assets/css/main.css', 
   'typeface-roboto/index.css',
   "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"
 ],

 sitemap: {
   path: '/sitemap.xml',
   hostname: "https://lovecaymanislands.com",
   gzip: true
 }, 

 googleAnalytics: {
   asyncID: async (context) => {
     return 'UA-184740092-1'
   }
 }, 
  plugins: [], 
  components: true, 
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
   '@nuxtjs/google-analytics' 
 ], 

  modules: [
    '@nuxt/content',
   '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
 ], 

 generate: {
    routes: [
     '/blog/my-first-blog-post' 
   ]
 },

  vuetify: {
   defaultAssets: false, 
   theme: {
     options: {
       customProperties: true
     },
     dark: false,
     themes: {
       dark: {
         background: '#00a86b'
       },
       light: {
         background: '#bfcec9'
       }
     }
   }
 }, 
  build: { }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide aws link? or more details about the code?

Comment: Your page "https://www.lovecaymanislands.com/sitemap.xml" is handled like a simple nuxt page (response = HTTP 200 + see page source code). You probably have an issue on the router config (maybe due to a wildcard, "_.vue" for eg.). Please share your "nuxt.config.js" file and your "pages/" structure.

Comment: @NicolasPennec hey thx I added nuxt config and printscreen of the pages structure. simply if I add new folder and vue page everything is fine. But using sitemap.xml and nuxtjs/content I assume it creates dynamic routes I tried to generate them using   generate { routes: {./blog/post1 }} it generates it but still not working on aws :(

Comment: @BallonUra thanks I added nuxt config and printscreen of files structure in dist

Comment: @RadimMotycka take a look to the part 3 of this tutorial: https://medium.com/@pascalluther/deploy-a-nuxt-spa-app-to-amazons-aws-amplify-74994d4326c1  (and add ".xml" to the list of redirect)

Comment: @NicolasPennec and by any chance? would you know my other issue. with nuxtjs/content module? I updated the question above/